# save byte array from java to image file in php

Tags: php, image

I am a Java guy and don't know about PHP. I am sending `byte` array of `image` to the PHP server and I want the PHP code to convert that `byte` array to `image` and save the `image` to a folder and return path of that file so that I can store it to a database

Java side:

```
  String image = Base64.encodeToString(chosenImage.getFileThumbnail().getBytes(),
                                Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

PHP Side:

```
$datax = $data['image'];
$datax = base64_decode($datax);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);



            move_uploaded_file($im , 'upload/' .'abc.png' );
            $path = 'http://xxxx/cc/zz/tt/' . $new_file_name;

        }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save an image created from imagecreatefromstring() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760559/how-to-save-an-image-created-from-imagecreatefromstring-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java already encoded the raw image data in base64 so in PHP you don't need to use `imagecreatefromstring` (unless you want to further manipulate it) since it is already an image.

This code is probably sufficient:

```
$datax = base64_decode($data['image']);
file_put_contents('upload/abc.png', $datax);
```