# Base64 Image SRC when I don't know the image type

Tags: javascript, html, image, base64

I've seen:

```
 src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG..."
```

or

```
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,LzlqLz..."
```

or

```
src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODl..."
```

Is the image type compulsory, or is there some way I can get the browser to figure it out and pass something like:

```
src="data:image;base64,R0lGODlh...
```

Comment: You can write some code to look at the first byte of data to figure out the image type. [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9899096/1990505)

Comment: @VikramDeshmukh He will have to convert it to JavaScript tho

Comment: no, you need to pass a valid dataURL to use it as a source in the DOM, and that includes mime.

Comment: even if you sniff the type, you still need to feed an img tag a dataURL that has the mime type in it, so why not just store it and avoid binary operations...

Comment: I guess you guys are right, I was just wondering if there was an inbuilt way to do it. After all, src="123.png" will load even if 123 is actually a jpg image, in Chrome. But that's not very nice.

Answer (score 0):

i am sure, you need strore what is the type of the image. Probably with your file extension