# Get image information from base64 encoded string

Tags: php, base64, fileinfo

I have base64 encoded string (Encoded from image).

```
$str = "......";
```

Q : How to get encoded image information ?

Like,

1) Image name.

2) MIME type.

3) Image extension.

4) Image size.

I try below code from [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061505/detecting-image-type-from-base64-string-in-php) but it gives only **MIME** type not other information.

```
$encoded_string = "....";
$imgdata = base64_decode($encoded_string);

$f = finfo_open();

$mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $imgdata, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
```

Many thanks.

Comment: **Downvoters** please explain what is the problem rather than downvote ?

Answer (score 3):

You can get information about the image using PHP's [`getimagesizefromstring`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php) function.

```
$encoded_string = "....";
$imgdata = base64_decode($encoded_string);

$data = getimagesizefromstring($imgdata);
print_r($data);

// outputs something like this
Array
(
    [0] => 544
    [1] => 184
    [2] => 3
    [3] => width="544" height="184"
    [bits] => 8
    [mime] => image/png
)
```

1) Base 64 encoded images will not have a filename

2) The mime type is given in the `mime` key, while key `2` contains one of the [`IMAGETYPE_`](http://php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php) constants

3) You can use `image_type_to_extension($data[2])` to get the proper image extension for the mime type

4) Image width is in key `0` and image height is in key `1`.