# how to convert base64 encoded image multi file formate in server side PHP

Tags: php, android

Hi i'm sending encoded base image string from android side and in server side i'm decoding the encoded image string and storing to folder, while saving to database i'm storing .JPG format. 
But the issue is if i upload .PNG image from android side it is storing in .JPG format but image is not visible in server side folder, and if i upload .JPG format it is visible in server side folder. Please help me out this problem.

**PHP Code**

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST['image1']))
    {
      $profile_picture = $_REQUEST['image1'];
      $target_path = "./upload/"."file"."_".time().".jpg";

      // **I want store multiple file forame** //

      $upload_img= "file"."_".time().".jpg";
      file_put_contents($target_path, base64_decode($profile_picture));
    }
    else
    {
        $upload_img = "image.png";
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by storing in jpg format? It looks more that just the extension of the file is always jpg. But it then contains a png image. In the right png format!

Comment: Let Android send the extension too. You can send as much parameters as you want. So your script can extract it. `$ext = $_REQUEST['ext']);`

Answer (score 0):

You can send file extension(.jpg, .png) in webservice from android side and retrieve it in your back-end PHP side then store it in variable and use it dynamically.

Comment: @Va I'm not getting in android side i'm sending only base64 encode string. and how to store dynamically.

Comment: Try this link to retrieve image extension in php - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061505/detecting-image-type-from-base64-string-in-php