# How to distinguish between Microsoft file types from a base64 String?

Tags: javascript, base64

Dears,
Good Day,

I have a case that receives a `file` with `base64` string format only, and there is no `meta-data` sent about this `file` and the requirement is to validate the the file type then accepts or rejects it,

I depend on this links below how to handle this issue. and it really helped.

[How to get MIME-TYPE from Base 64 String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976898/how-to-get-mime-type-from-base-64-string)

in this part:

```
....
var signatures = {
JVBERi0: "application/pdf",
R0lGODdh: "image/gif",
R0lGODlh: "image/gif",
iVBORw0KGgo: "image/png"
};
.......
```

this sample till now works on  `pdf`, `gif`, `jpg`, `tiff`, `png` and `text`.

but the issue in `docx`, `xlxs` , `pptx` the MIME type is the same for all

```
UEsDBBQABgAI..
```

I tried to Upload Many times the files on
[Base64.Guru](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/file) to convert `files` to `base64` and compare the `base64` result each time for each type.
the `MIME-TYPE` is the same `UEsDBBQABgAI`, there is no indicator or rule to distinguish between them,

any ideas ?

Comment: All of them are PK zip files, which is correct.