# How to check the file type with Laravel Facades?

Tags: php, laravel, base64, storage

Is there a convenient way to check the `file type` of a file with the `File` facade? I can check the `file extension` like so:

```
$ext = File::extension('623d91b094472.png');
```

I know I can derive the `file type` from the `file extension` but it would require some conditional string manipulation, so was wondering if there is a more convenient way to just get it from a `facade` like `File::type(...)` or such.

I need the `file type` because I'm encoding files in `Vue.js` and decoding them in `Laravel`, which requires the replacement of the `file type` and `file extension` in the `base64` string:

```
$file64 = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $request->file);
```

I've tried this:

```
$type = File::type('623d91b094472.png');
```

but it throws:

```
local.ERROR: filetype(): Lstat failed for 623d91b094472.png {"userId":16,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): filetype(): Lstat failed for 623d91b094472.png at /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/safa-ameedee.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:433)
[stacktrace]
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by file type?

You can extract the extensions from base64 with the following code, I don't think Laravel has any builtin methods for this.

```php
<?php

$base64string = "data:image/png;base64,...";
$fileExt = explode('/', explode(':', substr($base64string, 0, strpos($base64string, ';')))[1])[1];

echo $fileExt; // returns "png"

$fileType = explode('/', explode(':', substr($base64string, 0, strpos($base64string, ';')))[1])[0];

echo $fileType; // returns "image"
```

Also you can use something like [Image package](https://image.intervention.io/v2/usage/overview#reading-images) to create and manipulate the image from base64 string.

Comment: By file type I mean the `image` in front of the `/png` in the `base64` string. For example Vuejs encodes `png` and `jpg` files as `image` and `pdf` files as `application`. I was hoping there is some consensus between both frameworks on how to encode stuff and it might be supported.

Comment: I've update my code to show how to get image string. These strings are not reliable as per this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976898/how-to-get-mime-type-from-base-64-string

Answer (score 0):

You can use getClientMimeType() method on uploaded files.

```
<?php $file->getClientMimeType();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP's inbuilt function [getimagesizefromstring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php) to get image mime from image string/base64 as:

```
$imageData = getimagesizefromstring($data);

$mime = $imageData['mime']; // image/png
$ext = explode('/', $mime)[1]; // png

echo $ext; //png
```