# How to get mimeType from HTMLImageElement?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I checked [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) about `HTMLImageElement`.

But i couldn't find any information about `mimeType`.

I was able to find few docs about how to get mineType from `File` Object

But i need to get mimeType from `url` string

In my javascript logic i actually load the source to create `Image` object.
I hope i can find `mimeType` from this.

```
       const image = new Image();
       image.addEventListener("load", () => callBack(image));
       image.src = url;
```

Comment: you can use fetch() to preform a HEAD request on the image url, which will give you the mime in the "Content-Type" header it returns.

Comment: HTML elements don't have MIME type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert image to base64. The base64 string has mime type in the start. Extract mime type from that string. Check the below links.

Convert image to base64

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/how+to+convert+image+to+base64+in+javascript

Extract mime type from base64

[How to get MIME-TYPE from Base 64 String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976898/how-to-get-mime-type-from-base-64-string)

Regards,
omi

Comment: How do I get from the `const image = new Image();` to the `file` required in your answer?