# PHP: image mime type from image bytes

Tags: php, image, base64, mime

## Introduction

I have a base64 image string retrieved from a database: `$imageBase64Str`

I need to retrieve the mime from this content and display the image. This is what the following code does:

```php
function imgMime($imgBytes){
    if(is_null($imgBytes)){
        return(false);
    }
    if(strlen($imgBytes)<12){
        return(false);
    }
    $file = tmpfile();
    if(!fwrite($file,$imgBytes,12)){
        fclose($file);
        return(false);
    }
    $path = stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri'];
    $mimeCode=exif_imagetype($path);
    fclose($file);
    if(!$mimeCode){
        return(false);
    }
    return(image_type_to_mime_type($mimeCode));
}

$imageBytes=base64_decode($imageBase64Str,true);
if(!$imageBytes){
    throw new Exception("cannot decode image base64");
}
$imageMime=imgMime($imageBytes);
if(!$imageMime){
    throw new Exception("cannot recognize image mime");
}
header('Content-type: '.$imageMime);
echo($imageBytes);
```

## Question

The issue I have with this solution is that it requires me to write the 12 first bytes of the content to a temporary file. I am wondering whether there could be a simple way to avoid this without having to maintain a set of mimes manually. Also, I would like to avoid calling an external program (through `exec` for example) so that my code remains portable.

## Ideally

I wish there was a php function like `exif_imagetype_from_bytes`. My `imgMime` function would be simpler:

```php
function imgMime($imgBytes){
    if(is_null($imgBytes)){
        return(false);
    }
    if(strlen($imgBytes)<12){
        return(false);
    }
    $mimeCode=exif_imagetype($imgBytes);
    if(!$mimeCode){
        return(false);
    }
    return(image_type_to_mime_type($mimeCode));
}

$imageBytes=base64_decode($imageBase64Str,true);
if(!$imageBytes){
    throw new Exception("cannot decode image base64");
}
$imageMime=imgMime($imageBytes);
if(!$imageMime){
    throw new Exception("cannot recognize image mime");
}
header('Content-type: '.$imageMime);
echo($imageBytes);
```

## Edit: Solution based on selected answer

Thanks a lot to @Kunal Raut for the answer that allowed me to come up with the following solution:

```php
function imgMime($imgBytes){
    if(is_null($imgBytes)){
        return(false);
    }
    if(strlen($imgBytes)<12){
        return(false);
    }
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime=$finfo->buffer($imgBytes);
    if(strncmp($mime, "image/", 6) != 0){
        return(false);
    }
    return($mime);
}

$imageBytes=base64_decode($imageBase64Str,true);
if(!$imageBytes){
    throw new Exception("cannot decode image base64");
}
$imageMime=imgMime($imageBytes);
if(!$imageMime){
    throw new Exception("cannot recognize image mime");
}
header('Content-type: '.$imageMime);
echo($imageBytes);
```

This solution is a lot more elegant IMHO.

Comment: Short answer: That function doesn't exist. Yes, that sucks. Long answer: https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue I have with this solution is that it requires me to write the 12 first bytes of the content to a temporary file. I am wondering whether there could be a simple way to avoid this without having to maintain a set of mimes manually.

This is because of this part of your code

```
if(!fwrite($file,$imgBytes,12)){
        fclose($file);
        return(false);
    }
```

It makes you write minimum 12 bytes of data in the file and then lets the execution move forward.You can skip this `if()` and solve your first problem.

> I wish there was a php function like exif_imagetype_from_bytes. My imgMime function would be simpler

Yes there is such function which returns you the type of the *base64_decoded* string.

### `finfo_buffer()`

For more details regarding this function [Click Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-buffer.php).

**Use of function**

[Check out this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061505/detecting-image-type-from-base64-string-in-php)

Comment: Thank you very much @Kunal Raut , indeed, this `finfo_buffer()` function is what I needed. I will update my question with your solution.

Comment: Glad to help you:)