# How to check validity of base64 image in php?

Tags: php, base64

Does anyone have any idea how to know the base64 image validity?

This is my pseudo code to explain my problem:

```
$pic = `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ....`
if($pic is base64 image){
    echo "$pic is base64 image";
} else {
    echo "Not base64 image";
}
```

Comment: Both png and jpeg

Comment: First base 64 decode, then load with an image library that understands png and jpeg.

Comment: And what is the actual code for this solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact function for that but you can do this.

```
if ( base64_encode(base64_decode($pic, true)) === $pic){
    echo "$pic is base64 image";
} else {
    echo "Not base64 image";
}
```

Comment: I tried this code before but there is no output at all!

Comment: Any errors or warnings?

Comment: Now there is and output comes with: `Not base64 image`

Comment: I just edited the code to `if (base64_encode(base64_decode($pic, true)) !== false)` but it checked only for images if it base64 when I try to test for example `x.zip` it comes with no outputs

Comment: That is strange. TBH I have never tried to encode a zip file using Base64.

Comment: This is just for example.
Actually I want to check if the uploaded base64 is already image or not in `<input type="file">`

Comment: Maybe this can give you some idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061505/detecting-image-type-from-base64-string-in-php

Comment: The code can't work because the variable $pic (as given in the question) is not a base64 encoded string, but a data url that contains a base64 string in the last part, after `base64,`. You can't base64 decode the complete `$pic` variable, you would need to extract the base64 string first.