# php get image from url

Tags: php, image, url

I need to create a php file that return a JPEG image.
I wrote this code but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg;');
$p = 'http://....file.jpeg';
$a = file_get_contents('$p');
echo $a;
?>
```

What's wrong? I think that it is too simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a `<img>` tag.

```
 <?php 
    $src = 'file.jpeg';
 ?>

 <img src='<?php echo $src ?>'>
```

If this is not the functionality you looking for take a look at how to [Show image using file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286677/show-image-using-file-get-contents).

Answer (score 1):

remove the single quotes:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg;');
$p = 'http://....file.jpeg';
$a = file_get_contents($p);
echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: Still don't work. Do I must set any permission to file? Right now is 755

Comment: It works perfectly fine. I just checked. That must be something else not working in your case.

Comment: You have the file on disk? Then don't put a url in `$p`, but the local path. (if that is what you are doing). Hard to debug code if we don't know what the error is...

Comment: The file is into a server. How do retrieve any error?

Comment: What is the output of `file_get_contents` ? What is not working?

Comment: How do I check the value of file_get_contents? I start the php file from the server but the browser page is blank