# Laravel Intervention/Image make gif returns a static image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, intervention

this is the code that i use to get the image:

```
$img = \Image::make($ad['image_url']);
return $img->response();
```

it works, the only thing is that the image returned is static.

*When opening the real image url in a tab, it's animated*

is there a way to get the animated result?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, I solved it using another answer here on stackoverflow

```
$remoteImage = "http://www.example.com/gifs/logo.gif";
$imginfo = getimagesize($remoteImage);
header("Content-type: {$imginfo['mime']}");
readfile($remoteImage);
```

this returns the correct format

this is the url to the other answer from robjmills

[Show image using file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286677/show-image-using-file-get-contents)

Answer (score 0):

I think intervention library doesn't support animated Gif you may try other libraries directly like imagik or gd as given below
https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/176

Answer (score 0):

Send the mime type also in `response()`

```
$img = \Image::make($ad['image_url']);
return $img->response($img->mime());
```

`response()` method takes two parameter mimetype and quality in integer

Hope this helps.

Comment: how would i go about uploading this to S3. I need to get a stream to upload but when i get stream directly i loose the animation. The code already uses Image::make to resize and manipulate the image so i'd prefer to leave that code in.