# Assign Image SRC in php

Tags: php, file-get-contents

After retrieve image path from database I want to pass it to `<img>` tag to show up,
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21600709/1890313) solution, but I do not want to `echo` it, I want to assign it as `src` for image tag

I tried this:

```
$image = mysqli_fetch_array($user_images);
$img1 = $image['file_path'];
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img1));
$src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($img1).';base64,'.$imageData;
```

How can I assign $src to image, I tried this but no luck :(

```
<img id="img1" width="150" height="150" src="' . $src . '"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give us an example of the output of $src which didn't work. We have no idea what your content looks like. The basic idea seems fine, but maybe something is up with the contents.

Comment: `echo $src;` share the result

Comment: Is the `<img>` tag in the HTML part of your file?

Comment: @Nick Yes it is.

Comment: The last line with the HTML...can we assume this is part of a larger `echo` or `print` statement? Otherwise it won't output the variable's value, you'll just get the literal word $src written into the final HTML instead. Check the View Source option in your browser to see what is actually being created

Comment: "I do not want to echo it" -> I bet that yes, you want, you just don't know it, it should be something like `<img id="img1" width="150" height="150" src="<?php echo $src; ?>"/>`

Comment: @devpro I do not want to echo it as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: What's your objection to echo? And how do you expect to output the result of any PHP operation if you don't use it??

Comment: `<img id="img1" width="150" height="150" src="' . $src . '"/>` is it inside the php single quotes??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the HTML you still need to `echo` the value of `$src`. This should work:

```
<img id="img1" width="150" height="150" src="<?php echo $src; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with PHP tags like below:-

```
<img id="img1" width="150" height="150" src="<?php echo $src;?>"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Reasonable solution I can think of is

```html
<img id="img1" width="150" height="150" src="<?php echo $src; ?>"/>
```

but the code where you get the image source has to be above the image tag, so you have the `$src`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using PHP language and in Php, you can't pass variable directly in the Tag you have to set a variable in the PHP environment.
To create Php environment you can right `<?php ?>` or you can use to echo variable `<?= ?>` between these PHP tags you can pas your variables to echo and assign or anything else what you want to do.

```
<img id="img1" width="150" height="150" src="<?= $src ?>"/>
```