# MySQL Insert image in php the post functions return 0

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, blob

Im trying to import a profile picture for my users and insert it in the database in blob format. But when im running the code and i select an image i get file_get_contents() cannot be empty error

I have tried many solutions from other post related to this problem none of them worked.

**Controller:**

```
public function wijzigen()
{
    $foto = $this->input->post($_FILES['profielfoto']['tmp_name']);

    $fotoContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($foto));

    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');

    $gebruiker = new stdClass();
    $gebruiker->id = $id;
    $gebruiker->profileImage = $fotoContent;

    $this->load->model('gebruiker_model');
    $this->gebruiker_model->update($gebruiker);
```

**Model:**

```
    function update($gebruiker)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $gebruiker->id);
        $this->db->update('gebruiker', $gebruiker);
    }
```

**View:**

```
 <?php
    $attributes = array('name' => 'mijnFormulier', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'method'=>'post', 'accept-charset'=>'utf-8');
    echo form_open('Home/wijzigen', $attributes);
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo form_label('Profiel Foto:', 'profielfoto'); ?></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="profielfoto" id="profielfoto" required accept=".png"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <?php echo form_submit('knop', 'Wijzigen', 'class = "btn btn-login login-formcontrol"'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>


    </table>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Error:**

> ```
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty
>
> Filename: controllers/Home.php
>
> Line Number: 147
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/arne/Desktop/WebApplication/CodeIgniter/application/controllers/Home.php
> Line: 147
> Function: file_get_contents
>
> File: /home/arne/Desktop/WebApplication/CodeIgniter/index.php
> Line: 315
> Function: require_once
>
> I except an image to be in my database but the post isn't working
> ```

Thanks,

Comment: Is your routes configured for this `Home/wijzigen`?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286677/show-image-using-file-get-contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_FILES` and `$_POST` vars are 2 different things.

```
$foto = $this->input->post($_FILES['profielfoto']['tmp_name']);
```

should be:

```
$foto = $_FILES['profielfoto']['tmp_name'];
```

and please note this does not take in to account errors so you should probably check for that as a matter of course.