# Random URL File Get Content PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

i was trying to rotate url using file get content but there's little error which I am not able to figure out.

```
    <?php
    //Rotate
$urls = array();
$divs[] = '/fun.jpg';
$divs[] = '/nuf.jpg';

echo file_get_contents(src="'. $divs[rand(0, count($divs)-1)] .'");

    ?>
```

But it's not returning any random div.

Comment: What is the said little error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you just show images from same folder, as your PHP script is in, you should be able to do it like this. (**did not test it**)

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");

$divs[] = 'fun.jpg';
$divs[] = 'nuf.jpg';

echo file_get_contents($divs[array_rand($divs)]);
?>
```

You need to include header: [Show image using file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286677/show-image-using-file-get-contents)

And for picking random key from array you can use array_rand() function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php