# Unreadable content is returned when trying to show Nuxeo document

Tags: php, html, nuxeo

There is an API which can be used to get the preview of a Nuxeo document; it is like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/site/api/v1/repo/default/id/563c04bf-897d-48e5-863e-08cebeeccb06/@blob/file:content/@preview/image
```

It should show an image content :

[image]

Now I called it inside `file_get_contents` and I get unreadable content :

[image]

```
<?php

$opts = [
            "http" => [
                "method" => "GET",
                "header" => array("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode('Administrator:Administrator'),
                        "Content-type: image/jpg")
            ]
        ];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

echo file_get_contents("http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/site/api/v1/repo/default/id/563c04bf-897d-48e5-863e-08cebeeccb06/@blob/file:content/@preview/image", false, $context);

?>
```

I tried using `gzdecode` but I get `data error` exception although `magic_quotes_runtime` is not present in the `ini` file.

So how to fix it ?

**edit :**

Even if curl-ing it then I get the same result :

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/site/api/v1/repo/default/id/563c04bf-897d-48e5-863e-08cebeeccb06/@blob/file:content/@preview/image");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode('Administrator:Administrator'),
    'Content-Type: image/jpeg'
));

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

**edit 2 :**

Here are the headers from the dev tool :

```
    Request URL: http://tester/nuxeodociframe.php
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

    **Response Headers**

    Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 11 Jan 2021 13:50:53 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) PHP/7.2.18
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.18

    **Request Headers**

    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: qa_id=3976046217316149434; qa_noticed=1; RT="z=1&dm=tester&si=9brcldlzx2&ss=kjsghu2u&sl=0&tt=0"; __utma=244493312.1444286480.1610362906.1610362906.1610362906.1; __utmc=244493312; __utmz=244493312.1610362906.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Host: tester
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show image using file\_get\_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286677/show-image-using-file-get-contents)

Comment: do you have any PHP error logs?

Comment: This looks like valid JPEG file data, possibly with one byte (0xFF) missing from the start. Have you tried `cURL`ing it instead of using the stream API?

Comment: @pheromix please update your question

Comment: done ; I removed the `\r\n`s

Comment: @EugenRieck , even if I curl it then same result , see updated post

Comment: There is no PHP error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser needs to know how to decipher the information it receives.
In this case you must "inform" him that it is a picture.
Therefore you will add:

*Edit:*
add this line before any echo

```
header("content-type: image/jpeg");
```

If the image is not jpeg you must add a suitable [header](https://help.accusoft.com/PrizmViewer/v10.1/Config/MIME_Types.html)

Also remove the close tag `?>`

Comment: It does not work : see my edit post including the response header. Although I already set the Content-type header to be image/jpg

Comment: @pheromix run this code:    `<?
header("content-type: image/jpeg");
echo file_get_contents("https://images.pexels.com/photos/4806731/pexels-photo-4806731.jpeg");`